# Return JavaScript value to PHP through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, return

Yes, there are lots of topics about this, but no one really posts the full code so I do not understand what to do. I would appreciate help. I am using some custom API (jqgrid) and will explain what some things do.

This is how it goes:

First there is a PHP function

```
$getUnitID = <<<getUnitID //This is how you start a javascript function in this API
function(rowid, selected)
{
    var selr= null;
    if(rowid != null){ 
        selr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
        return selr;
        } //All this does is give me a value based on a row I click. It works great.

}
getUnitID; // End of JS function
```

Now I know I need to execute some AJAX. But I don't know when or where or how. I know about reading the manual but that doesn't always help. I am still lost (it's been 3 hours). Here is what I gather should be the AJAX, but where does it go?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "webpage.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: selr,      
        success: function(data) { 
        alert (data);
        }
    });
```

I don't know how to implement that AJAX call.

The final goal is to place the data from var "selr" into a simple php function such as $myVariable.

### Thank you for the help and time.

This is how I've tried to combine

```
$getUnitID = <<<getUnitID
function(rowid, selected)
{
var selr= null;
if(rowid != null){ 
    selr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    //alert (selr);
    return selr;
    }
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getId.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {selr:selr},      
            success: function(data) { 
            alert (data);
            }
        });

}
getUnitID;
$grid->setGridEvent('onSelectRow',$getUnitID);
$pdfButton = array("#pager",array("caption"=>"Create PDF", "onClickButton"=>"js: function(){parent.location='/pdftkphp/example/download.php?id= ". 6 ." '}"));
```

And the seperate PHP page is just

```
<?php
$rId = $_POST["selr"];
echo $rId + "some ajax stuff";
?>
```

Comment: What does your `webpage.php` look like? Or is that the php file from above?

Comment: The `data` variable in the ajax call is the data that will be sent to the server via post.  If you want to give it a particular name, you will have to do: `data: 'myPostName=' + selr`.

Comment: Yes. One problem I realized was I my url parameter was the same page, not a new one. Thank your for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, hopefully this helps. In your AJAX call, your `url` is calling webpage.php - so presumably that page should be waiting for an incoming variable. Something like

```
$myVariable = $_POST["selr"];
```

So, that above statement is checking the `POST` for a variable called `selr`, well, we have to tell the AJAX call to send your variable as `selr`, so change your `data` in the AJAX call to be a key/val pair:

```
data: {selr:selr},
```

Now, that `success` function with the parameter `data` is the data you `echo` back from your PHP side. So say you have:

```
 $myVariable = $_POST["selr"];
 echo $myVariable + "some ajax stuff";
```

Your `data` will now contain the output of that `echo`. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for this help, I have implemented these changes. The next question is, where (I'm sorry, I really need literal guidance) do I stick that AJAX function? ie what part of the JS code? Right now I put it after     return selr;}

Comment: Wherever you need to call it, probably inside a `click` handler, just make sure it has accesss to that `selr` variable.

Comment: So that AJAX function should not always be sitting inside the JS function? And "has access to that selr variable" that's essentially the problem I've been having this whole time, right? How do I get access to that selr var? If my AJAX function is not inside the JS function, then I still cannot get access to it..Man I am confused

Comment: That `function(rowid, selected)` you have above, I'd imagine you want the AJAX call inside that function on the end of it. That way it will fire each time that function is executed.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for the assistance. I've posted the full code above if you have any more input (I have to leave) thanks so much!

Comment: That `return` statement is going to leave the function before the AJAX is executed, fyi